# PHP - Check if a text is containing a word

Tags: php

I want to check if my text contains one of words, probably from an array like:

$array = array('BIG','SMALL', 'NORMAL');

Example of what can contains my text variable:
$text = "BEAUTIFUL BIG UMBRELLA...";
$text = "SMALL GREEN TEE-SHIRT";

I want to set a variable size; 
--> if my text contains the word BIG, I want to set the variable size='BIG'....

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What will happen to `BIGGIE SMALLS MID-SIZED RED T-SHIRT`? Or more generally, what should happen on the occurrence of multiple keywords in a sentence?

Comment: The text come from a csv file and contains only one occurence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is with regular expressions, as bart and IVIR3zaM said. Here is an alternate usage:

```
<?php
$text = "This is a normal text where find words";
$words = array('BIG','SMALL','NORMAL');

// It would be a nice practice to preg_quote all your array items:
// foreach ( $words as $k => $word ) {
//  $words[$k] = preg_quote($word);
// }

$words = join("|", $words);
$matches = array();
if ( preg_match('/' . $words . '/i', $text, $matches) ){
    echo "Words matched:";
    print_r($matches);
}
```

You can check it working here http://ideone.com/LwSf3P

Remember to use the /i modifier to find matches non-case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be afraid of regular expressions... Try

```
 if(preg_match('/\b(BIG|SMALL|NORMAL)\b/', $text, $matches)) ...
```

The `\b` is to make sure you indeed have an entire word; append "i" after the slash in the pattern if you want case insensitive match.

Answer (score 1):

Use strpos to test for a single word:

```
if(strpos($text, $word) !== false) { /* $text contains $word */ }
```

http://php.net/strpos

Comment: $word can not be an array here ! And I want to use it like an array, any solution to test for multiple words ?

Comment: @Bizboss there are loops to handle arrays. Do you have idea of any?